# chatbot using deep learning and flask.but the bot doesn't give a response

Tags: python, html, flask, deep-learning, chatbot

I'm working on building a chatbot using deep learning model and flask but the bot does not give a response and it shows this error

```
GET /run?msg=salut HTTP/1.1" 404 -
```

this is the html code

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/static/style.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>SAM Chatbot</h1>
    <div>
      <div id="chatbox">
        <p class="botText"><span>Salut je suis le Bot.</span></p>
      </div>
      <div id="userInput">
        <input id="textInput" type="text" name="msg" placeholder="Message">
        <input id="buttonInput" type="submit" value="Send">
      </div>
      <script>
        function chatbot_response() {
          var rawText = $("#textInput").val();
          var userHtml = '<p class="userText"><span>' + rawText + '</span></p>';
          $("#textInput").val("");
          $("#chatbox").append(userHtml);
          document.getElementById('userInput').scrollIntoView({block: 'start', behavior: 'smooth'});
          $.get("run", { msg: rawText }).done(function(data) {
            var botHtml = '<p class="botText"><span>' + data + '</span></p>';
            $("#chatbox").append(botHtml);
            document.getElementById('userInput').scrollIntoView({block: 'start', behavior: 'smooth'});
          });
        }
        $("#textInput").keypress(function(e) {
            if(e.which == 13) {
                chatbot_response();
            }
        });
        $("#buttonInput").click(function() {
            chatbot_response();
        })
      </script>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

this is the code including the api by describing the request http. first, i loaded the model then i built a function witch used predict() to predict responses.

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, jsonify
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import keras
from keras.models import load_model
import keras.preprocessing.text
import os
import h5py
from utils import loadChatbot 
import pickle
from chatgui import chatbot_response, getResponse

#from utils import translate

#! /usr/bin/python
# -*- coding:utf-8 -*-




app = Flask(__name__, static_url_path='/static')

chatbot_model = loadChatbot('chatbot_model.h5')

"""global graph
graph = tf.get_default_graph()""" 



@app.route('/')
def accueil():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/',methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def chatbot_response():
    print ("run")
    userText = request.args.get('msg')
    if userText != '':
     res = chatbot_model.predict(userText)
    return res

@app.errorhandler(500)
def server_error(error):
    return render_template('error.html'), 500   
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you don't set the port for Flask (must bind to the port provided by Heroku):

```
app.run(debug=True, port=int(os.environ.get("PORT", 5000)), host='0.0.0.0')
```